# Is it possible to get the string of the name of a property in its get and set?

Tags: c#, .net, properties

I want to store and retrieve my configs from database. I have written two methods `setConfig(“configName”, value)` and `getConfig(“configName”)`  and I use them in my properties:

```
public long MyConfig1
            {
                get
                {
                    return getConfig("MyConfig1");
                }
                set
                {                    
                    setConfig("MyConfig1", value);
                }
            }
```

But I have to write the string of the name for all of properties.
Is it possible to get name or any reference to the current property in set and get in C#?
Something like this:

```
public long MyConfig1
            {
                get
                {
                    return getConfig(getName(this));
                }
                set
                {                    
                    setConfig(getName(this), value);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a method to use the [caller-information attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/mt653988.aspx):

```
// Put this anywhere
public static string GetCallerName([CallerMemberName] name = null)
    => name;
```

Importantly, when you call this, *don't* supply an argument: let the compiler do it instead:

```
public long MyConfig1
{
    get => GetConfig(Helpers.GetCallerName());
    set => SetConfig(Helpers.GetCallerName(), value);
}
```

Or you could use the same attribute in the `GetConfig` and `SetConfig` methods, of course, and then just not supply an argument when you call them.

Comment: Just curious, why is a helper method preferred over `nameof`? Is this to extract the actual logic (which now is implemented using `CallerMemberName`) ?

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was my answer!

Answer (score 3):

If you have access to the `getConfig` and `setConfig` methods, modify those methods as shown below. This is the most clean solution.

```
    // using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

    public long MyConfig1
    {
        get
        {
            return getConfig();
        }
    }

    private long getConfig([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
    }
```

However if you do not have access to modify those methods, use `nameof` in each setter and getter.

```
    public long MyConfig1
    {
        get { return getConfig(nameof(MyConfig1)); }
    }
```